# Access - Form & report combo, query issue

Tags: ms-access

I want to have a combination of a form & report, the only part that is a form allows the user to choose which project they want data on. I've included a screenshot of what it will look like. The problem is when I put the control source for "Total Postage($)" the following code is generated:

```
=SUM([tblWinner]![Postage cost])
WHERE  «Expr» [tblWinner]![ProjectID]="PL981"
```

Whether or not «Expr» is there, i get the error:
"You may have entered an operand without an operator."

Thanks in advance.

Screen:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YF9M.jpg

Answer (score 0):

What you want is the [DSum() function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa172193%28v=office.11%29.aspx).

```
=DSum("[Postage cost]", "[tblWinner]", "[ProjectID] = 'PL981'")
```

If it needs to be dynamic:

```
=DSum("[Postage cost]", "[tblWinner]", "[ProjectID] = ' & _
        {column name or form variable here} & '")
```

Please comment with any follow up questions.